# Gatsby - Getting undefined for MySQL id

Tags: mysql, primary-key, gatsby

I want to get into Gatsby.

My current problem is, that i can not get the "id" from mysql database.

The result for "id" (Primary "AUTO_INCREMENT") is "mysql__Homepage__undefined" (expected "16" - represented in DB))

The result for "id2" is "4" (represented in DB)

My table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `homepage` (
  `id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id2` smallint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `release` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'on',  
  `headline` varchar(250) NOT NULL,  
  `lastmodified` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My Gatsby GQL is

```
 allMysqlHomepage {
    edges {
      node {
        headline
        id
        id2
      }
    }
  }
```

Result for id

```
mysql__Homepage__undefined
```

Result for id2

```
4
```

Someone run into same problem?

Best regards

Comment: Unrelated tips, don't use MyISAM, use INNODB by default. Use TIME/DATETIME types for lastmodified rather than string types.

Comment: From docs this looks closely tied to what queries are defined in the plugins structure. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-mysql2. Can you show that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution:**
In gatsby-config.js I had to set the idFieldName to my id field from db:

````
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-mysql`,
      options: {
        connectionDetails: {
          host: 'localhost',
          user: 'test',
          password: 'test',
          database: 'test'
        },
        queries: [
          {
            statement: 'SELECT * FROM test',
            idFieldName: 'id',
            name: 'test'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```
````